# Best practice for Subscriber Key for Trigger API SMS Sends

Tags: marketing-cloud, subscriber

I have a question regarding SMS subscriber key. I know for an email sends it's best practice to have subscriber key other than email  but unfortunately not enough documents on SMS subscriber keys. Is it best practice to use Phone number as Sub key or it should be other than Phone Number.

Thanks
Deepak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subscriber Key is very much historical ExactTarget terminology and used for Email.

In SMS you want to associate to the Contact Key (which in turn should be related to Subscriber key)

You'll want to register the contacts mobile number in Mobile Connect with a commonality with other data objects/records.